# MySQL subquery with IN clause

Tags: mysql

This query works fine:

```
SELECT country_name FROM countries WHERE country_id IN (23,86,79)
```

so I can get the list of countries' name based on those country_id. But what I want is to get them with a subquery like:

```
SELECT country_name  FROM countries WHERE country_id IN (SELECT office_id FROM countries WHERE country_code='FRA')
```

I can get the first name of the office Id and not all (in this case should be 4). The office_id and country_id are Int. Any helps?

Comment: Why you dont use this ?? - SELECT country_name FROM countries WHERE country_code='FRA'

Comment: the query looks fine. show us some data and expected results so we can see what goes wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

why do you need such wrong/long turn query. your posted query (below) with subquery

```
SELECT country_name 
FROM countries 
WHERE country_id IN ( SELECT office_id 
                      FROM countries 
                      WHERE country_code='FRA' )
```

Can be simpliy

```
SELECT country_name 
FROM countries 
WHERE country_code='FRA';
```

Comment: The subquery returns several id (es: 12,22,43,9). With these id I need to get the corresponding country name, The problem if that if I wrote something like "...IN (12,22,43,9)" the whole query works fine and I get four rows but with the Select as subquery I get only one value

Comment: You don't need the subquery in first place. just use the query in answer with the required where condition ... should work fine. if not then do `select count(*) from countries where country_code='fra'` and see what's the count ... that will tell you what's wrong.

Comment: Sorry guys, I've been not so clear. the inner query, "SELECT office_id FROM countries WHERE country_code='FRA'", returns a string with comma separated values (es: "12,22,223") and I would use this with IN clause

Comment: Ohh!! man ... no that's a comma separated list and you can't use it in `IN` caluse since it's not properly quoted. You should consider normalizing your table structure rather.